# Returning result of AsyncTask to calling activity in android app

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm looking to connect my android app to a WCF RESTful webservice and so far am doing allright on getting it set up. However now I'm at the point of splitting out the execution onto the background thread via AsyncTask<>

Rather than have the AsyncTask classes embedded within the activity .java files though, I would prefer to split them out to a separate package so they can be used by multiple activities and fragments within the app, however (and I may be missing something obvious here), how do I then marshall the result of the AsyncTask back to the calling Activity? I understand that I will get the result of doInBackground() passed to onPostExecute() - but then how do I pass the result back to the calling activity or fragment?

Similarly how can I call progress notifications back on the parent activity as the separate AsyncTask<> classes will have no knowledge or visibility of UI components.

In C# I would probably have passed through a callback delegate to the constructor of the AsyncTask<> pointing to a method on the parent activity and then invoked the callback delegate with the params of the result when the task finished. Is it something similar with Android?

Comment: use interface as a callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to interact with RESTful services maybe you can save yourself some trouble using:

- [ion](https://github.com/koush/ion) by Koush
- [retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) by Square
- [volley](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley)

Retrofit example:

Retrofit turns your REST API into a Java interface.

```
public interface GitHubService {
  @GET("/users/{user}/repos")
  List<Repo> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
}
```

The RestAdapter class generates an implementation of the GitHubService interface.

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint("https://api.github.com")
    .build();
```

GitHubService service = restAdapter.create(GitHubService.class);

Each call on the generated GitHubService makes an HTTP request to the remote webserver.

```
List<Repo> repos = service.listRepos("octocat");
```

Source: http://square.github.io/retrofit/

You can also read about AsyncTask VS Volley VS Retrofit [here.](http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by creating an interface with a method. Make your activity implement this interface. Then pass a reference of the activity (using this keyword) to the Async Task which can be created as a separate class through its constructor. Then in the postExecute() method of the Async Task, call the method of the interface to come back to the activity.